# How to use agregate functions without using group by on all columns in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

For e.g. I have this table X

```
    Date1  *Date2  *Price  * Brand*Comment  
    ****************************************
    111016 *131016 *100    *a     *h   
    121016 *131016 *200    *a     *i  
    111016 *131016 *300    *b     *j
    121016 *131016 *100    *b     *k
```

I want sum(price), brand, comment in max(date1) for date2 131016.

```
    sum(price) *brand *Comment
    **************************
    300        *a     *i
    400        *b     *k
```

I was trying a query something like this

```
select s1.sum(price),s1.brand,s2.comment
from X s1, X s2
where s1.date2='131016'
    and s1.brand=s2.brand
    and s2.date1=(select max(date1) from X where date2='131016')
group by s1.brand;
```

It appears my approach is wrong here.
What should be my approach for the select query to show data in above manner? Please keep in my mind that there will be more than 20 columns in the table similar to price for which I need to show the sum.

Comment: How do you determine which `comment` value to show?  Perhaps you want `max(s2.comment)` rather than `s2.comment`.  But that may or may not be what you're really after (taking the `max` of 20 separate columns so that you're pulling data from a bunch of different rows would be suspicious at least).

Comment: To @JustinCave's point. How do you determine that you want comment `i` and `k` in your output? Why not comment `h` or `j`? Or do you not care and you just want it to return a random comment for each brand?

Comment: What is the data type of `date1` and `date2`? If they are numbers or strings instead of "date", comparisons (like MAX) will give the wrong answer. You need the dates to be in date datatype, or else use `to_date()` around the strings (if they are strings).

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use Analytic Function **SUM(col1) OVER (PARTITION BY col2, ...,coln ORDER BY col2,..,coln)** like below :

```
select sum(s1.price) over(partition by s1.brand),
       s1.brand, 
       s2.comment
  from X s1, X s2
 where s1.date2 = ‘131016’
   and s1.brand = s2.brand
   and s2.date1 = (select max(date1) from X where date2 = s1.date2);
```

While we aggregate data, GROUP BY is necessary. But GROUP BY can be avoided by using PARTITION BY(which in turn is analog of GROUP BY).

Check out this link for better understanding of analytic functions ..
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions182.htm#SQLRF06115

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE X ( Date1, Date2, Price, Brand, "Comment" ) AS
SELECT DATE '2016-10-11', DATE '2016-10-13', 100, 'a', 'h' FROM DUAL UNION ALL   
SELECT DATE '2016-10-12', DATE '2016-10-13', 200, 'a', 'i' FROM DUAL UNION ALL  
SELECT DATE '2016-10-11', DATE '2016-10-13', 300, 'b', 'j' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-10-12', DATE '2016-10-13', 100, 'b', 'k' FROM DUAL;
```

**Oracle Query**:

```
SELECT SUM( price ) AS total_price,
       brand,
       MAX( "Comment" ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY date1 ) AS "Comment"
FROM   X
WHERE  Date2 = DATE '2016-10-13'
GROUP BY brand;
```

**Output**:

```
TOTAL_PRICE BRAND Comment
----------- ----- -------
        300 a     i       
        400 b     k
```

Comment: Notes... `comment` is a reserved word, I would use `comm` or `comment1` or similar. `sum(price)' seems like an odd aggregation - one hopes in the real-life data, one is adding total sales amounts or so, not "prices" (for the same item over different dates). There was a WHERE clause somewhere in there too.

Comment: @mathguy I have used the column names the OP has used. The where clause is trivial to add in.

Comment: @mathguy This is just a table that I made up at the moment of writing to explain my problem. I just wrote the column names that came in my mind. The actual problem that I am working on is not even similar. at the slightest.